How to use dashboards imported from metricbeat into opensearch-dashboard [Opensearch 2.13.0 & metricbeat 7.12.1]?
I am using a docker-compose with opensearch 2.13.0, opensearch-dashboard 2.13.0 and metricbeat 7.12.1.  After a series of back and forth and going through multiple write ups, I can see the metrics in the opensearch-dashboard using the discovery service. Particularly these 2 resources https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch-Dashboards/issues/656 and https://www.electricbrain.com.au/pages/analytics/opensearch-vs-elasticsearch.php were particularly useful.
To replicate, here are the configs:
docker-compose.yml
services:
  opensearch:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.13.0
    container_name: opensearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - compatibility.override_main_response_version=true
      # - "plugins.security.disabled: true"
      - "OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=AFQrb42jMYEyXeSnLaef"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - ./opensearch-data:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

  opensearch-dashboard:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.13.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboard
    environment:
      - "OPENSEARCH_DASHBOARDS_ALLOW_IFRAMES=true"
      - "OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=https://opensearch:9200"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
    depends_on:
      - opensearch

  metricbeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat-oss:7.12.1
    container_name: metricbeat
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
    depends_on:
      - opensearch

networks:
  opensearch-net:

metricbeat.yml
metricbeat.modules:
- module: system
  metricsets:
    - cpu
    - memory
    - network
    - filesystem
  period: 10s
  processors:
    - drop_event.when.regexp:
        system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://opensearch:9200"]
  username: "admin"
  password: "AFQrb42jMYEyXeSnLaef"
  ssl.verification_mode: "none"
  index: "metricbeat-7.12.1"
  # setup.dashboards.enabled: true

setup:
    kibana:
      host: "http://opensearch-dashboard:5601"
    dashboards:
      enabled: false
    template:
      name: 'myapp'
      pattern: 'myapp-*'
      enabled: false
    ilm:
      overwrite: true

One the stack was up, I logged into the metricbeat container to export the index-pattern, the template and some dashboards.
docker exec -it metricbeat /bin/bash
./metricbeat export template > metricbeat.template.json
./metricbeat export index-pattern --es.version 7.12.1 > metricbeat.index-pattern.json
exit

The files in question are available in this public dropbox tarball link
Then I copied them out of the docker
docker cp metricbeat:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.template.json ~/Downloads/metricbeat.template.json
docker cp metricbeat:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.index-pattern.json ~/Downloads/metricbeat.index-pattern.json
docker cp metricbeat:/usr/share/metricbeat/kibana/7/dashboard/Metricbeat-host-overview.json ~/Downloads/Metricbeat-host-overview.json

Deleted the following block out of the template.json file
"lifecycle": {
  "name": "metricbeat",
  "rollover_alias": "metricbeat-7.12.1"
},

Imported the files as documented in the resources shared above
curl -i -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin:AFQrb42jMYEyXeSnLaef -XPUT https://localhost:9200/_template/metricbeat-7.12.1 -d @metricbeat.template.json
curl -i -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "osd-xsrf: true" -u admin:AFQrb42jMYEyXeSnLaef -XPOST 'http://localhost:5601/api/opensearch-dashboards/dashboards/import?force=true' -d @metricbeat.index-pattern.json
curl -i -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "osd-xsrf: true" -u admin:AFQrb42jMYEyXeSnLaef -XPOST 'http://localhost:5601/api/opensearch-dashboards/dashboards/import?exclude=index-pattern&force=true' -d @Metricbeat-host-overview.json

I can see the metricbeat data when I create the index pattern and go on the "discover" mode.

However there is no existing dashboard I could use even know all the imports were successfull to opensearch-dashboards.



I am not sure what I am missing . Please point me to the right direction if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.
